# How to use AWS OpenVPN with a domain name and redirect the IP address to the hostname?

Tags: openvpn, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS OpenVPN deployed in AWS marketplace. I want to connect on URL using domain only `https://example.com` not accessible via `https://132.x.x.x` is there a way public IP is not accessible?

I cannot find any Nginx running or Apache service to configure for a redirection from the IP address to the hostname.

Is there any approach this can be accessible only via a domain name?

Comment: hi this is already configured both on DNS and webui. what i need is the public ip should not be accessible. If i will access the openvpn via ip it should be redirected to https://vpn.example.com

Comment: What do you mean by public IP should not be accessible?

Comment: this is the test config i did on my dns recrod which is godaddy A vpn.edventuresph.com 34.230.136.191 on web ui of openvpn vpn.edventuresph.com so normally in aws you have assign public ip on ec2. so my dns records and hostname are both configured. yes it is accessible. but the assign public ip on my ec2 is also accessible https://34.230.136.191. what i need is if you access the url which is https://34.230.136.191 should be redirecting to my https://vpn.edventuresph.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the hostname to `vpn.example.com` on the Admin Web UI.

Once you have done that, you need to go to your DNS server or registrar and set a `DNS A (Address)` record and point it to the IP address of your server.

For example: `vpn.example.com     A    123.123.123.123`

Comment: hi this is already configured both on DNS and webui. what i need is the public ip should not be accessible. If i will acces the openvpn via ip it should be redirected to https://vpn.example.com